# Can I assign a survey for some to take once, and others to take multiple times?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, survey-list

I'm creating a survey that we're sending out to two departments. One department only needs to respond to the survey once, but one department needs the capability to do multiple responses.

Do I need to create two separate surveys, or is there a way to allow/disallow retakes at the customer level?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need 2 separate surveys, one configured for only 1 response and one for multiple responses.  You can create 1 survey and save it as a template to provision the other on to save a bit of time.

This will aloow you to set permissions as needed and provide better analysis as the 2 groups of data aren't intermingled (which I guess could be a bad thing, depending on what you're looking for in the results).

Answer (score 1):

Using standard out of the box features you are going to have to create two surveys. I am pretty sure there is no other way to do it without writing an entirely new feature. It may not be worth the time and effort to do such a thing.